# MailKit returns empty From on a fetch

Tags: fetch, mailkit

I was testing MailKit with Fetch on the mail Envelope. summary.Envelope.From[0] gave an exception after getting emails from the mail server. On inspection, the From field is shown on the original mail file as:

...
...
From: Root User <>
...

Gmail shows this mail as (unknown sender)

I can attach the header if necessary. Is there a standard way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do what GMail does which is effectively:

```
if (summary.Envelope.From.Count == 0)
    return "(unknown sender)";
```